# SSL аутентификация в Oracle

Tags: oracle, ssl

Пытаюсь настроить SSL взаимную аутентификацию Oracle. База данных на windows server 2008R2, на ней же Active Directory, адрес 192.168.56.12. Клиент Windows 7, адрес 192.168.56.11.
listener.ora сервера:

```
TRACE_LEVEL_LISTENER = ADMIN
TRACE_FILE_LISTENER = listener
TRACE_DIRECTORY_LISTENER = C:/app/Kefir/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/trace
LOG_FILE_LISTENER = listener
LOG_DIRECTORY_LISTENER = C:/app/Kefir/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/log
LOGGING_LISTENER = ON
 
SID_LIST_SSL_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
 (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ORCL)
 (SID_NAME = ORCL)
 (ORACLE_HOME = C:/app/Kefir/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1)
    )
  )
 
#SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
SSL_LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = 192.168.56.12)(PORT = 2484))
  )
WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE=
     (METHOD = FILE)
     (METHOD_DATA =
    (DIRECTORY=C:/wallet_server
     )))
```

sqlnet.ora сервера:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (TCPS, BEQ, NTS)
 
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE
SSL_CIPHER_SUITES= (SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5)
SSL_VERSION = 0
WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
 (DIRECTORY = C:/wallet_server)
    )
  )
TRACE_DIRECTORY_SERVER = C:/app/Kefir/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/trace
trace_level_server = SUPPORT
TRACE_FILE_server = trace_server
```

sqlnet.ora клиента:

```
WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE=
     (METHOD = FILE)
     (METHOD_DATA =
    (DIRECTORY=C:/client_wallet
     )))
SSL_VERSION = 0
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (TCPS,BEQ,NTS)
SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH = TRUE
SSL_CIPHER_SUITES= (SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5)
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES,EZCONNECT)
TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT = C:/client_wallet
trace_level_client = USER
TRACE_FILE_CLIENT = trace_user
```

tnsnames.ora клиента

```
orcl =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = 192.168.56.12)(PORT = 2484))
    (CONNECT_DATA=
 (SERVER = DEDICATED)
 (SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)
    )
    (SECURITY=(SSL_SERVER_CERT_DN="CN=WIN-SFJD57T6M7B.myora.local"))#доменное имя сервера
```

Пытаюсь конектиться
[image]

lsnrctl status
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Порт 5500, хотя в listener.ora указан 2484. Перезапускаю listener и теперь порт 1521. Как мне тогда это изменить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что делать?

Comment: А что на сей раз не получается? Почему вы не правили прошлый вопрос, а задали новый?

Comment: я решила начать заново по другой инструкции. В прошлом вопросе пришлось бы много добавлять

Comment: А что за база кроется за  алиасом SSL?

Comment: два алиаса на одну базу, 12с

Comment: И какие с ними ошибки?

Comment: TNS no listener

Comment: А  почему вы в вопросе привели одну ошибку, а в комментарии другую?

Comment: потому что что бы я не добавляла, возникают разные ошибки. Возможно ошибка где-то в записях, а умные люди мне на неё укажут)

Comment: Хорошо, тогда с первой ошибкой мы разобрались -  алиас SSL не сушествует. Замените ее в вопросе на следующую ошибку.

Comment: мне проще уже удалить тот вопрос, это было так давно) я отмечу, что вы помогли мне

Comment: А при чем тут прошлый вопрос? Я имею ввиду текущий.

Comment: Ошибка #2: А прослушиватель у вас запущен на сервере? Там запустите - `lsnrctl status`. Что показывает?

Comment: Теперь, у вас прослушиватель на порту  5500, а вы подключаетесь к 2484.

Comment: Сложилось впечатление, что вы меняете коннфигурацию прослушивателя, но не обновляете ее в вопросе.  Где у вас указан порт 2484, а где 5500?

Comment: 2484 в listener.ora, 5500 нигде

Comment: 2484 у вас под именем SSL_LISTENER, который, не вижу, где вы пытались хоть раз запустить. 5500 у вас третья строчка в Listening endpoints summary, если вы опрашиваете статус  прослушивателя по умолчанию - LISTENER. Так что, _5500 нигде_, это не совсем соответствует действительности.

Comment: в listener.ora сервера я SSL_LISTENER заменила на LISTENER, теперь с клиента выдаётся ошибка ORA-12560 TNS:protocol adapter error

Comment: Теперь смотрите в трэйс файл прослушивателя, почему ошибка. Что показывает статус прослушивателя. Попробуйте - tnsping orcl.

Comment: tnsping orcl выдаёт TNS:No listener ora 12541

Comment: То есть, круг замкнулся. На порту, по которому обращается tnsping, нет прослушивателя.

Comment: но как же так, я же всё указала как в туториале. Может быть надо как-то ещё по-другому?

Comment: Если даже оф.документации нельзя вслепую доверять, то каким туториалам в сети, тем более. Попробуйте разбить задачу на части и решать их отдельно, а не всё вместе. Например, раз возникли сложности с прослушивателем, то попробуйте сначала добавить ещё один endpoint без SSL, просто ещё один порт 2521.

Comment: попробую, спасибо

Comment: Поймите, когда нет полной информации - логов, конфигов, выводов команд, то трудно угадать, почему появляется та или иная ошибка.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на тутор, который вы сейчас используете. Как время появится, попробую проверить его.

Comment: Здесь http://www.petefinnigan.com/forum/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=tools_free;action=display;num=1128363187 и здесь http://software.firstworks.com/p/oracle-tlsssl-encryption-with-self.html

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверил [туториал](http://software.firstworks.com/p/oracle-tlsssl-encryption-with-self.html), исползуемый ТС. При проверке обращался к следующим главам документации:
[Configuring Secure Sockets Layer Authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-secure-sockets-layer-authentication.html#GUID-6AD89576-526F-4D6B-A539-ADF4B840819F), [Database Net Services Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netrf/index.html).
В результате - провереная на работоспосоность конфигурация.

#### Пошаговая инструкция

Имеется:

- `db.local.net` -  сервер БД
- `app.local.net` - машина с клиентом *Instant Client*
- используются параметры по умолчанию, поэтому все файлы конфигурации почти пустые,
  клиент в соотоянии без проблем подключится к БД по *easy connect*

1. На сервере БД необходимо создать кошельки для сертификатов (также для клиента, т.к на нём отсутствуют необходимые утилиты), и добавить в них самоподписанные сертификаты:

   ```
   $ cd $ORACLE_BASE

   $ orapki wallet create -wallet  wallet/ -pwd Wallet0Pass -auto_login
   $ orapki wallet add -wallet wallet/ -pwd Wallet0Pass \
       -dn CN=db.local.net \
       -keysize 2048 -self_signed -validity 365 # ok

   $ orapki wallet create -wallet  wallet.app/ -pwd Wallet0Pass -auto_login
   $ orapki wallet add -wallet wallet.app/ -pwd Wallet0Pass \
         -dn CN=app.local.net \
         -keysize 2048 -self_signed -validity 365
   ```
2. Добавленные сертификаты надо экспортировать и добавить в другой кошелёк, как доверенный сертификат:

   ```
   $ orapki wallet export -wallet wallet/     -dn CN=db.local.net  -cert db.crt -pwd Wallet0Pass
   $ orapki wallet export -wallet wallet.app/ -dn CN=app.local.net -cert app.crt -pwd Wallet0Pass

   $ orapki wallet add -wallet     wallet -trusted_cert -cert app.crt -pwd Wallet0Pass
   $ orapki wallet add -wallet wallet.app -trusted_cert -cert db.crt -pwd Wallet0Pass
   ```
3. На сервере БД надо добавить следующее в конфигурационные файлы:

   *sqlnet.ora:*

   ```
   NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
   WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = FILE)
       (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY = /app/oracle/wallet))
   )
   SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = ALL
   SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE
   SSL_CIPHER_SUITES = (SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
   ```

   *listener.ora:*

   ```
   WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = FILE)
       (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY = /app/oracle/wallet))
   )
   SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE
   LISTENER = (DESCRIPTION_LIST = (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = db.local.net)(PORT = 1521))
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = db.local.net)(PORT = 1544)))
   )
   ```

   Небходимо перестартовать прослушиватель:

   ```
   $ lsnrctl stop
   $ lsnrctl start
   $ lsnrctl status
   [...]
   Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=db.local.net)(PORT=1521)))
   STATUS of the LISTENER
   ------------------------
   Alias                     LISTENER
   [...]
   Listening Endpoints Summary...
     (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=db.local.net)(PORT=1521)))
     (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=db.local.net)(PORT=1544)))
   The listener supports no services
   The command completed successfully
   ```

   Доступные сервисы БД, кторые не прописаны в параметре `SID_LIST_LISTENER`, будут зарегистрированны автоматически в течении минуты.
4. На машину с клиентом необходимо скопировать любым доступным способом (использовал утилиту `scp`) кошелёк с сервера БД. Затем дополнить конфигурационные файлы:

   ```
   $ scp -r root@dbsrv:/app/oracle/wallet.app/ ./wallet
   ```

   *sqlnet.ora:*

   ```
   NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
   WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = FILE)
       (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY = d:\app\oracle\wallet))
   )
   SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = ALL
   SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE
   SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH = TRUE
   SSL_CIPHER_SUITES = (SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
   ```

   *tnsnames.ora:*

   ```
   pdb1s = (DESCRIPTION = 
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = dbsrv.local.net)(PORT = 1544))
       (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = pdb1))
       (SECURITY = (SSL_SERVER_CERT_DN = "CN=db.local.net"))
   )
   ```
5. Как результат, протокол устанавливаемого соединения - `TCPS`:

   ```
   $ sqlplus -l me/me@pdb1s

   SQL> select sys_context ('userenv','network_protocol') proto from dual;

   PROTO
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   tcps
   ```

Comment: здравствуйте, извините за задержку, что за dbsrv.local.net? Я попробовала туда ставить доменное имя сервера, выдало 12560 TNS protocol adapter error. И у вас при перезагрузке листенера написало, что он  The listener supports no services, а у меня Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance

Comment: _что за dbsrv.local.net_, это полное имя сервера (_FQDN_) (всюду заменил его на db.local.net, в одном месте забыл). В локальной сети разрешение имен должно быть настроено,т.е. `ping dbsrv.local.net` с клиетской машины должен работать. Если не работает, то во всех конфиг файлах прописывайте IP.

Comment: такой пинг работает в обе стороны. У меня не db.net.local, а WIN-...B.myora.local

Comment: _И у вас при перезагрузке листенера написало, что он The listener supports no services_, это так, а в следующей строке что написано?

Comment: тогда наверное дело не в этом. Уже намаялась с этим ссл. Попробую через керберос. Спасибо вам большое, это была настоящая эпопея)

Comment: Мне кажется, где-то "обидная" опечатка, всё должно работать.